# Update only records that have a unique id

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to update records in a table only if there is only one record for that ID. I then also need to insert records if there is more than one record already.

```
UPDATE survey, survey_errors 
SET survey.depth = survey_errors.max_depth
WHERE survey.depth=-1
AND survey.hole_id=survey_errors.hole_id 
AND survey_errors.max_depth Is Not Null
```

But now how to find out if survey.hole_id is unique?

Comment: Is it for MS-Access or SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested, in this way you can find `uniqueId`:

```
SELECT
    col1, col2
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    col1, col2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

OR

You can simple use `DISTINCT`. It will return for you result without duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2
FROM YourTable
```

AND

Update should be like this (This will update only unique values):

```
UPDATE TblName
SET Anything = Anything2
WHERE Anything IN ( 
    SELECT
        Anything 
    FROM
        TblName
    GROUP BY
        Anything
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) =1
)
```